# Is there Django middlware to accept multiple 'requests' in a request and return multiple 'responses' in a response?

Tags: django, web-services, json, web-applications

I'm looking for Django middleware to let me issue several queries in one request and combine the [JSON] results to send back in one request? To illustrate:

If I have two web methods:

`/query/show/widgets` => `['widget1', 'widget2']`

`/query/show/sprockets` => `['sprocket1', 'sprocket2']`

and I want to do this:

`/multiple:/show/widgets;/show/sprockets`

which might return something like

```
{'widgets': ['widget1', 'widget2'],
 'sprockets': ['sprocket1', 'sprocket2']}
```

I could write this myself but there may already be something that can do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt this exists, so you'll pretty much have to do it yourself.

Write a middleware that looks for your separator, split those URLs, resolve them and call the view, then merge the results.